# The connection to IBOutlet button and its code is getting disconnected soon after building the app (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iboutlet

I am using Firebase in my Swift app to allow users to logIn through their gmail. So according to its documentation, I imported all necessary libraries including "GIDSignInUIDelegate".Then I added a button. Then tried to subclass it as "GIDSignInButton" in the storyboard but its not getting added and even when I am entering the subclass name as "GIDSignInButton" its not successfull. Then I tried to add below line in the view controller "@IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!" and tried to connect the button to this outlet. But its getting connected and soon after I build the app, the connection is again getting disconnected.

So could anyone please help me in finding out whats the issue here.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t really understood your problem but will try to break it down for you, so here are 2 steps that you might try:

1. Check if you really have imported all necessary libraries = `pod ‘GoogleSignIn’`, run pod install again and reopen file that would have extension .xcworkspace. And after then you can try to add button and have type of GIDSignInButton
2. If the first step is not working try to create it programatically, here is a sample code of that:

   ```
   private var btnSignIn : UIButton!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let btnSize: CGFloat = 100
       btnSignIn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: btnSize, height: btnSize))
       btnSignIn.center = view.center
       btnSignIn.setImage(UIImage(named: "google_logo.png"), for: .normal)
       btnSignIn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnSignInPressed), for: .touchUpInside)

       //Circular button
       btnSignIn.layer.cornerRadius = btnSize/2
       btnSignIn.layer.masksToBounds = true
       btnSignIn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
       btnSignIn.layer.borderWidth = 2
       view.addSubview(btnSignIn)
   }

   @objc private func btnSignInPressed() {
       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
   }
   ```

P.S. sometimes if you see in xcode when you build a project or open the project again that the IBOutlet or IBAction is not circled (connected) anymore just hold <kbd>⌘</kbd> and press storyboard and you will see if the connections are still on or not. Hope that helps!